# Map data from Data frame R to Java class in Eclipse

Tags: java, json, r, eclipse

I have a data frame in R ed I read it in a java class with JRI library. I have to map the data contained in the data frame in java classes. I thought of turning the data frame in json object and build their POJO but I need help. Someone can help me? I use Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers (Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)). Thanks!

This is my R script called "Rmongo.R:

```
library(rJava)
library(RMongo)
mongo <- mongoDbConnect("DBunical")
dbShowCollections(mongo)
results <- dbGetQuery(mongo, "Veicolo", '{}', 0, 3)
View(results)
```

results is my data frame.

This is my java class:

```
import org.rosuda.JRI.REXP;
import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;

public class rmongo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Creating Rengine (with arguments)");

    String[] Rargs = {"--vanilla"};
    Rengine re = new Rengine(Rargs, false, null);

    System.out.println("Rengine created, waiting for R");

    // the engine creates R is a new thread, so we should wait until it's
    // ready

    if (!re.waitForR()) {
      System.out.println("Cannot load R");
      return;
    }

    System.out.println(re.eval(".libPaths(\"C:/Users/Stefania/Documents/R/win-  library/3.2\")"));

    System.out.println(re.eval(".libPaths()"));
    re.eval("source(\"C:\\\\Rmongo.R\")");
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any special relation to eclipse. What's the problem? Don't you get the data? Don't you know how to parse JSON? What does the data look like?

Comment: Eclipse has nothing to do with your problem.  It's an IDE.

Comment: I do not know how to pass the data in the data frame of the variables in java. For now I have created a test data frame with four numeric variables and three-tuples of this values.